# Windows phone 8.1 with Ionic framework, white blank space above keyboard

Tags: cordova, keyboard, windows-phone-8.1, ionic-framework

Facing issue in windows phone 8.1 with ionic development.

When input text area is focused keyboard is shown but cursor location is not properly aligned to typing location and a blank white bar is displayed just above the keyboard. if i type cursor still points below the input area. If i click text area again then cursor point to proper location and blank white bar is removed.

Cordova version : 5.0.0
Ionic version : 1.3.20

Comment: Hello! Could you solve this issue?